# Excel: Autonumber cells based on adjacent cell value in a continuous way

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cell

after some research and attempts I am unable to create a formula that I need. Basically, what I have now is this:

[image]

The formula:
`=IF(XOR(NOT(ISBLANK(B11)),NOT(EXACT($B11,$B10))),"",COUNTA(B$2:B11))`

But what I want is this:

[image]

In other words, I want to count in column A and show consecutive numbers for each new unique, non-blank value in column B, without it "skipping" the numbers.

Comment: @SRJ you are right, added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",IF(B2<>B1,MAX($A$1:A1)+1,""))
```

If the value in B is a new one, look for the previous highest number in A and add 1, otherwise do nothing.